# How to save listbox value into database in MVC4 and EF?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a registration form which allows the admin to choose the menu item for a particular user.

My aim is to save the selected menu items into the database as comma seperated values.

The problem is value of the `MENU` is always set to null,irrespective of updating the model.

**User.cs**

```
public partial class User
{
    public User()
    {
        this.Mobilizations = new HashSet<Mobilization>();
    }  

    ...
    public string ADDRESS { get; set; }
    public string PHONE { get; set; }       
    public string MENU { get; set; }

 }
```

**UserViewModel.cs**

```
 public class userViewModel
{
    public User User { get; set; }       
    public SelectList MenuList { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="Select some menu items")]
    public string[] MenuIds { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller.cs**

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(userViewModel model)
    {           
       var menuIds = string.Join(",", model.MenuIds);
       var user = new User()
       {
           MENU=menuIds
       };           
        TryUpdateModel(model);
        if (ModelState.IsValid) //<= The value of MENU not getting updated
        {               
            _db.Entry(model.User).State = EntityState.Modified;
            _db.SaveChanges();
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Create");
    }
```

**View**

```
   <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Menu", new { @class = "col-sm-2 control-label " })
        <div class="col-sm-10 ">                
            @Html.ListBoxFor(model=>model.MenuIds,Model.MenuList,new {id="menuListBox", @class = "chosen-select",multiple="multiple",
            style="width:350px"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model =>model.MenuIds)
        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, you're creating a user object and then not saving it anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly you should be doing the following:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(userViewModel model)
{           

    TryUpdateModel(model);
    if (ModelState.IsValid) //<= The value of MENU not getting updated
    {               
        model.User.MENU = string.Join(",", model.MenuIds);
        _db.Entry(model.User).State = EntityState.Modified;
        _db.SaveChanges();
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Create");
}
```

Assuming that your menu items are posting correctly, without seeing the View it is difficult to tell.

Comment: @ksg View looks ok to me.

Comment: Thanks for your reply . I have a doubt , is the piece of code `TryUpdateModel(model)`  necessary.I commented it out and tested it,its working..

Comment: @ksg No problem. I don't think that will be updating anything as the menu item you are updating is not shown in the view model, it is a separate one that you are updating within the user object, if that makes sense. That is why I re-set it back in the above example. Good luck with the rest. :)